# Did Naruto stack Sage Mode with Sage of Six Path Mode?

Tags: naruto

Naruto received Sage of Six Path Mode from Hagaromo. At this moment, what was Naruto "final form"?

- KCM + Sage Mode(Toad) + Sage of Six Path Mode?
- KCM + Sage of Six Path Mode?

If it's the latter, did his Sage Mode(Toad) transformed into Sage of Six Path Mode? Is there any other explanation?

Comment: Really? Unreasonable downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naruto had already unlocked KCM+Sage Mode before getting extra powers from Hagoromo(when he was fighting Sage-Obito alongside Minato)

Sage of six paths chakra gave him truth seeker orbs,along with a small piece of each tailed beast.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: So, did he use KCM+Sage Mode+Sage of Six Path Mode?

Comment: Yep.He used them all

Answer (score 0):

The sage mode was originally triggered by the tailed beasts Naruto received from Hagoromo. He however originally unlocked the kurama sage mode himself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a transformation. His Sage Mode (Toad version) evolve into Sage of Six Path mode. Same thing happen with Sharingan evolved to Rinnegan. Because both power up is derived from Rikudou Sennin or Hagoromo.